# connection to nodejs SQL Server on mac

Tags: sql-server, macos

Probably a simple thing, but new to me.  I could not find a post that helps with this, so I expect that I am doing something silly without knowing.

I have a SQL Server database running in Docker on mac & can easily log in to the 'sa' account.

I made another id for an application to connect to the same database.

```
CREATE LOGIN tisApp WITH PASSWORD='pa$Sw0rd'
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'tisApp'
```

However, when I try to connect to it, like this...

```
mssql -u tisApp -p pa$Sw0rd
```

I receive an error...

```
My-iMac:~ my$ mssql -u tisApp -p pa$Sw0rd
Connecting to localhost...
Error: Login failed for user 'tisApp'.
My-iMac:~ my$
```

The MS documentation states that an id created this way should be able to connect but...I cannot.

When I check the logs, they show:

> Login failed for user 'tisApp'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]

Comment: Can you see the connection attempt in the logs? If so, what do they say?

Comment: The message is this, but the password does match....  Login failed for user 'tisApp'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 172.17.0.1]

Comment: Then the password you are providing when you try to log in and the password you set for the Login are not the same.

Comment: Hi Larnu.  I see that is what is being reported, but I don't know how they are not the same.  Is there something about the syntax I show in the initial post that is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-case this helps anyone, this was pretty simple answer after a small experiment.  SQL Server was not accepting special characters through mssql for some reason.  So, I updated the commands as follows and everything works perfectly now.

Of course, this is not a good password, but it works ok for now.

SQL Server:

```
CREATE LOGIN tisApp WITH PASSWORD='pasSw0rd'
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'tisApp'
```

Command line:

```
mssql -u tisApp -p pa$Sw0rd
```

Now, I get...

```
My-iMac:TIS my$ mssql -u tisApp -p pasSw0rd
Connecting to localhost...done

sql-cli version 0.6.2
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
mssql>
```